# How to render a Rails engine's views inside the host app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I need some help getting a rails engine to communicate with my host application.

I've got a standard layout file in the engine.

```
app/views/layouts/my_engine/application.html.erb
```

and my host app has the standard

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

In the host app, I've gota partial that contains a nav bar.  I would like to use this nav bar in pages that are generated by the engine.

I have no idea how to do this.

My first attempt at solving this was to create another version of this file in my host app, thereby overwriting the original behavior.

```
app/views/layouts/my_engine/application.html.erb
```

I was hoping this strategy would work, but the nav bar partial now has no knowledge of the routes that belong to the host app.  It throws a 'no method' error on any named route in the host app.

So how do I allow the engine to render views in the host app, but ultimately rely on the host app's structure for pages as defined in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`?

Comment: Maybe, this one helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7175241/1005661

Comment: I found this post, which answers my question:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615067/render-engine-within-application-layout][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615067/render-engine-within-application-layout

Comment: You have a couple options 
1) make your engine controllers inherit from main application's ApplicationController and use the main application layout. You can use this in your engine application_controller:
 class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController

2) You can fix the problem with your routes in your view overrides by prepending your paths with main_app (eg: main_app.resource_path)

Answer (score 3):

Copying this from the comments, so that other people don't miss it:

> I found this post, which answers my question: [Render engine within application layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615067/render-engine-within-application-layout)

credit to OP for finding the solution